Can you use Parameters to scale part of an Object?
I have designed a cylinder shaped object, which has an inner design with precise measurements, that fits over another object. This object will be used as a template to create different sized objects, where ONLY the outer diameter will be changed, and then 3D printed.
As such, I intend on copying the original object, and then only want to change the Outer diameter (which has numerous faces, edge loops, extrusions etc) to the precise measurements (in millimetres) as required.
Is there a way this can be done?
IF I change the X and Y dimensions in the Item Properties, this affects the WHOLE object, which I do not want to do, as I only want to change the outer diameter - see image attached - Red Inner circle to remain as is, the outer Green circle to change.


Do you want to scale the details on the outer cylinder also when scaling the green cylinder ? Or do you want these details to "just move outwards" ? In the first case, the depth is increasing by increasing the outer diameter...

You can easily use "vertex groups" for that.

Select the inner side of the cylinder
Go to the data tab of the object
Create a new vertex group and rename it to "Inside"
"Assign" the selection to this group

You can do the selection the way you feel more comfortable, I did it with x-ray on (alt+z), using the "lasso" selection tool.

This creates a vertex group named inside with the inner part of the points.
Then you can click "select" menu and "invert" (ctrl+i). This will select the outer part. Following the same idea, you can create a new vertex group named "Outside" and assign.
Whenever you want to perform operations, you can go to the "Vertex Groups" list, select a group and click the "Select" button there. This will give you only the points you want to edit.

This will also be available in "Geometry Nodes" if you need, by using the "Named Attribute" node.

For making it the right diameter, ideally you should save the template with outer diameter = 1.
Then you just:

Select the outer points
Scale on shift+z (means scale on X and Y, not Z)
Type the diameter you want.


Thanks, used this method, with some slight changes.
I created a circle with the same dimensions as the original. I then changed the X and Y values to the new dimensions in mm, and then used the X and Y Scale for the Outer ring dimension.

In my example the outer circle diameter is 2m.
I created a shape key, where I selected all outer vertices, set the cursor at center, set the pivot point at 3D cursor, pressed S, Shift Z, 2, Enter, so that the outer diameter become 4m.
Now I created a custom property on the object, name = dimension, type = float, default value 2, min 2, max 4, precision 2, step 0.01.
Right click on the custom property > Copy as new driver.
Right click on the shape key > Paste driver.
Right click again > Edit driver.
Change mode from Average value to Scripted Expression, type the expression (dimension-2)/2, so that moving the slider from 2.00 to 4.00 activates the shape key from 0.0 to 1.0.


When you will have to export the object, create a new shape key (New shape from mix), then delete the driven shape key, then delete the Basis, then delete the new shape key, to consolidate the new dimension.

Seems a little complicated for my skill at the moment - but may consider later on. Thanks
